# Angular 10 “No definition found for …” in HTML component in Visual Studio Code

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, angular10, html-components, go-to-definition

I'm working with angular 10 in VSCode and everything was working fine until today.
Suddenly I can't go to definition from HTML component neither via F12, right click - Go to definition nor Ctrl+click.

Go to definition works just on typescript components, also I don't get any errors except "No definition found for...."

I've tried updating VS Code, reinstalling VS Code and  reinstalling extensions:
Angular Essentials by John Papa
Angular Language Service
Angular Snippets

Also I experience the same behavior on all of my projects (two of them).

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

work for me....

To enable the latest Language Service features, set the strictTemplates option in tsconfig.json by setting strictTemplates to true, as shown in the following example:

content_copy
"angularCompilerOptions": {
"strictTemplates": true
}

https://angular.io/guide/language-service

Answer (score 4):

In my case, after several tries, I found the cause was an ***ngIf="whatever"** in the parent DOM element and in some other cases in other elements in the same level, after removing this, all definitions were reachable again... this is [a bug](https://github.com/angular/vscode-ng-language-service/issues/1109)
As a workaround, I downgraded Angular Language Service to 11.2.0

Comment: I had to downgrade from 14.2 to 13.3.4

Comment: Similarly, I had to to downgrade to v14.1.0- https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Angular.ng-template

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it helps anyone, but I found that I just needed to update to the latest Angular Language Service. I switch to using VS code preview and noticed a similar error compared to when I was using Webstorm.

After I installed the Angular Language Service package under VS extensions, it fixed this issue. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Angular.ng-template

Comment: Let's add that you need to have strictTemplate set to true otherwise the extension features will barely work.